# linux mint freeze

Tags: freeze, linux-mint, dpkg

Linux Mint freezes after a couple of seconds the desktop loads, in a way that I have to shut the power in order to reboot; the mouse doesn't move, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't do anything and I think even the hard disk stops.

This doesn't happen every start but when it does happen, I have to start recovery mode and run the option "dpkg", the description is "repair broken packages" or something like that. If I don't do that and start the system normally the something happens again.

I have some clues that might help:

The first time I installed Mint I had to install my wireless driver manually. The system didn't freeze before this but since I installed the driver immediately after the Mint installation that might just easily be a coincidence. Even so after I discovered the dpkg trick, for the first couple of times I did it, I found my wireless driver uninstalled and I had to reinstall it.

The thing is I can't be sure that the problem is my wireless driver because the relation is not direct enough.
Still letting you know what my wireless apapter is might help: Realtek L 8723

The next thing I am going to do is to wait until it happens again and post the system log here.

Comment: Sorry I Should have add my Mint version: Linux Mint 13 Maya